# Error redicrect to home page when rewrite url custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I hava custom post type

```js
function anime_post_type() {
  register_post_type('anime', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Anime',
      'singular_name' => 'Anime',
      'add_new' => _x('Thêm Anime', 'animefrost'),
      'add_new_item' => 'Thêm Anime Mới',
      ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'story', 'with_front' => FALSE),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    )
  );
  //flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}
```

And i want to rewrite

http://localhost/Anime/story/one-pice/?ep=1 to http://localhost/Anime/story/one-pice/ep/1

With my code

```js
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "ep";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );


add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules');
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^story/([^/]+)/ep/([0-9]+)$','index.php?post_type=anime&ep=$matches[2]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}
```

What is error in my code ???
Please help me , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your rules on rewrite_rules_array filter

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'dcc_rewrite_rules');
```

Now add your new rules and return them

```
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    $aNewRules = array('story/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=story&ep=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
```

check [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array)

Don't forget to save the permalinks

You can access the query string via `$wp_query->query_vars['ep']`

Comment: I am try but , it is redirect to is_front page